# HTML5 'required' validation in Ruby on Rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, validation

I can't see this question anywhere else, it's hopefully a quick and easy one.

How can I use HTML5 validators, such as 'required', in my forms (ruby on rails)?

Eg, How would this basic form look if I used HTML5 validation in it?

```
<%=form_for @testimonial do |t|%> 
<dl>
  <dt><label for="testimonial_rating">Rating</label></dt>
  <dd><%=t.select :rating, Testimonial.ratings%></dd>
  <dt><label for="testimonial_content">Comments</label></dt> 
  <dd><%=t.text_area :content, :rows => 3%></dd>
  <dd><button class="button success">Submit Review</button></dd>
</dl>
<%end%>
```

It goes without saying that server side validation is still required.

Comment: You will likely need to use js to get this to work on safari: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684657/safari-is-not-acknowledging-the-required-attribute-how-to-fix-it

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Ah, it was easy `:required => true`

eg: `<%=t.text_area :content, :rows => 3, :required => true%>`

Comment: any idea how to achieve the same by using simple_form?

Comment: same way... required: true

Answer (score 42):

Just to add on, if you have an email field, you can also use 'pattern' attribute to validate the format of email

```
<%=form.text_field :email, :required => true, :pattern => '[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}' %>
```

:)

Comment: why would you do this when you can use `form.email_field`?

Comment: As a side note, never ever try to validate regex with email. It's going to let all sorts of edge cases slip through, or block actually valid ones. You'd be better off allowing everything and checking serverside by trying to send an email and requiring them to click a link in it before anything happens.

Answer (score 11):

Addition to @prashantsahni answer. You can also use **type = 'email'** instead of regex pattern, then your erb-template will look like this:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, id: 'user_email', type:'email', required: true, placeholder: "Email" %>
```

[More info about form validations using html5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)

Comment: this failed for me - adding `type: 'email'` did not add any HTML5 validation and allowed me to proceed.

Comment: `f.email_field` is already created with `type='email'` as far as I've experienced.

Answer (score 5):

This is a little example with the common attributes and for required you only add required:true, but dont forget apply this validations in your backend.

```
<%= f.text_field
    id: "yourID",
    class: "yourCLass",
    placeholder: "Your message",
    maxlength: 14,
    required: true
%>
```

Answer (score 5):

New Syntax
`<%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", required: true %>`

Answer (score 4):

This could be easily done by adding `:required => true` parameter into your input fields:

For example

```
f.text_field :first_name, :required => true
text_field_tag :first_name, nil, :required => true
```

Pushing the boundary abit further, you could add in pattern matcher for your input, such as email:

```
f.email_field :email, 'Email', :required => true, :pattern => '[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the pattern matching comment but you really should have read the responses to the question - including my own one - which renders the first part of this answer redundant. You must not have read the other answers. You should really do that before answering here. Not that I know more than you, as you can see I have a very small reputation value compared to yours.

Answer (score 3):

For completing other answers, there is an awesome [gem html5_validations](https://github.com/amatsuda/html5_validators) which makes the most of the HTML5 validations reading from ActiveRecord Validations from the model. No extra code needed, just installing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this if nothing works

```
include_blank: false, required: true
```