# Using the Rails form_for "req" option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I am trying to make a ruby tag field a required field client side only and I am trying to do so via:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => 'Event Title', :id => "form-field-first", :class => "form-field", :class => "req" %>
```

but it still submits no prob if the field is empty.  Is it more complicated than this? do I have to go in my .rb file and make a special required class?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you trying to style the field as a required field or actually make the field required? For the former, see @mdestantis' answer. For the latter, see my answer.

Comment: @ZachyBear, there's no `form_for` "req" option; can you be more clear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 'required' validation in Ruby on Rails forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541983/html5-required-validation-in-ruby-on-rails-forms)

Comment: Nope, never asked that question, this is no duplicate.

Comment: Why am I getting down voted for trying something wrong?=( Isn't that what stack overflow is all about? I saw the class "req" on a resource somewhere and I tried to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good ideas but I found it on a similar question, all you need in any ruby tag is:

```
:required => true
```

so I can,

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => 'Event Title', :id => "form-field-first", :class => "form-field", :required => true %>
```

and bingo! super simple and could not find the option on the docsXD

Comment: this is all and well if you want to validate **client side only**. This is not rails specific and is instead just setting the HTML attribute of the input element. A user can modify the DOM and bypass this easily.

Answer (score 2):

As noted at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence,

You should use `validates :field, presence: true` in your `model.rb` file to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should write the tag class attribute as a space-separated string:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, 
                 :placeholder => 'Event Title', 
                 :id => "form-field-first", 
                 :class => "form-field req" %>
```